# adding item onClick react using state not working?

Tags: reactjs

hello I want to add a new item on every icon click to the current item that is already on display
so for example if I have 1 item and I click the icon I want them to be 2 items so every click should increment the component by 1 I tried add + add it returned [object object]
any solution for this ?

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Item from './Item';

function itmes(props) {
  const [add, setAdd] = useState({items :[<Item/>]});
    return (
        <ul>
        {add.items}
         // on every click an <Item/> shoud be added 
        <FontAwesomeIcon className="changable margin-left" onClick={()                       
        {setAdd(add.items.push(<Item/>))}} icon={["fas", "plus-circle"]/>
        </ul>
        )
   }
```

Comment: Try `onClick={() => {setAdd((p) => [...p, <Item/>])}}`

Comment: Also: storing component instances in state is an anti-pattern. Instead, store identifiers in state and create the instances when you loop over them in the return.

Comment: @TomaszStaszkiewicz TypeError: p is not iterable

Comment: `add.items.push` would return the number of items in your array. `setAdd` would then be saving an integer

Comment: @Jackhammer Sorry, it should be: `onClick={() => {setAdd((p) => ({ items: [...p.items, <Item/>]}))}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add an item to a list you should use this syntax:

```
onClick={() => {setAdd({items: [...add.items, <Item/>]})}}
```

With the spread operator (`...`) you basically create a copy of the old list and merge that with the new item together into a new list that you update to be the new state.

Also I think you haven't used the arrow function sintaxt correctly. Your code should look either like this (arrow function syntax):

```
 onClick={() => {setAdd({items: [...add.items, <Item/>]})}}
```

Or like this (with function keyword):

```
onClick={function() {setAdd({items: [...add.items, <Item/>]})}}
```

Comment: it worked but i hade to do it this way onClick={() => {setAdd({items: [...add.items, <Item/>]})}}

Comment: Glad I could help! I also updated the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
  function Items(props) {
    const [add, setAdd] = useState({items :[<Item/>]});
      return (
        <ul>
         {add.items}
          <FontAwesomeIcon
           className="changable margin-left"
           onClick={()=>setAdd(prev=>{items: [...prev, <Item/>]})}
           icon={["fas", "plus-circle"]/>
        </ul>
      )
   }
```